# What to do with debugging and fix-my-code questions posted by non programmers

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, close-reasons

On a fairly regular basis [I come across a question like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914076/select-multiple-form-element-not-outputting-form-selections-just-array-php).

The poster in this case is fairly honest in explaining that he employed a programmer to write code, and now wants to change it.  He isn't really a programmer, and obviously doesn't want to pay someone to pick up the software and is coming to SO to get some free consulting.

I want to close the post for a few reasons.  First off, the issue is trivial and simple for any intermediate developer to solve.

I also don't see any real long term value of a question like this for future developers.  It's essentially a one-off.

Am I off base in thinking this question should be closed?

Comment: _Who_ posted a bad question or _why_ they weren't able to post a good question really isn't important. If it should be closed, then it should be closed regardless of any of that. The only thing that really matters is if the question meets the criteria for closure.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out to people that the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) specifies that the site is for *professional and enthusiast programmers*, but I agree with Makoto that this isn't a close reason.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Gotta love when comments that should have been answers get more votes than the actual answers posted ;)

Comment: @Shane I guess it could have been an answer. I just added it as a comment because I wasn't answering the actual question _"Am I off base in thinking this question should be closed?"_ I didn't want to answer a specific-question question with a general statement, especially when I hadn't even looked at the specific question in question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd think you're doing the right thing for the wrong reasons.  Allow me to explain.

> First off, the issue is trivial and simple for any intermediate developer to solve.

This isn't a valid reason to *close* a question.  It's a valid reason to *downvote* a question for sure, but not closure.  Closure implies that the post is temporarily off-topic or has some temporary issue with it which can be fixed until such a time the question is reopened.  Downvoting implies that the question isn't well-researched.

> I also don't see any real long term value of a question like this for future developers. It's essentially a one-off.

This has more prudence with determining if a question is on-topic, but can be difficult to evaluate from a non-PHP developer's standpoint.

For example, even though I'm not versed in PHP - I'm actually quite allergic to it - I don't see anything in the question that automatically makes me think, "Oh, this is a poor question."  The only thing that slightly annoys me is this line...

> It was built by a freelance PHP developer I no longer have access too, and my PHP is not great.

...***only*** because it's not germane to the actual question at hand.

So, to summarize:  The question *probably* should be closed ***and*** edited to be made more on-topic if at all possible.  Removing the above line would be a start.  From there, it could be reopened if the community feels that it's a question they wish to answer.

Comment: I guess the specifics are important.  In this case the question boils down to the fact that when a form has a select multiple list, and the user actually chooses multiple items, PHP turns that into an array.  This isn't a bug or a surprise, but something obvious that can be found easily in the manual and is known or discovered by any legitimate developer, professional, hobbies or student, who has ever posted an html form to a PHP script.  The first answer provided solves the user's problem.  So essentially the poster, has no debugging skills, not even cursory knowledge of the language ...

Comment: .. and spent no time trying to figure out the trivial answer to his question.  What I'm asking is, is this alone grounds for closing a question, even if on the face of it, the question is viable?

Comment: It's kind of obvious that they don't have any knowledge if they're asking a question...don't judge them so harshly for that fact.  I maintain:  I would legitimately contract some kind of disease if I spent more time looking at PHP code, but the fact that they didn't know shouldn't preclude them from asking at all.  You seem to be punishing them for not knowing PHP.

Comment: Yes, well I'm not sure it's punishment to expect someone who is coming to a programming community, ostensibly to get help with programming and to learn, actually be a programmer, or student or have genuine interest in the language involved.  This is the reason for my post.  If I'm wrong about the expectations of SO, I'm happy to have that clarified for me.

Comment: @gview Logically we do have that expectation, but it doesn't have anything to do with how we choose to vote on questions. Votes should only be based on the merits of the question itself. If you think it's not useful or has something wrong with it, vote based on that, not based on the user.

Comment: It should be noted that closures are not a bug or a surprise and is obvious to any seasoned javascript programmer but **nobody** on stackoverflow would think for one second that closures are offtopic. Duplicate yes (there are tons of questions and several good reference answers) but not offtopic. Just because something is obvious and not a surprise to one person does not make questions about it bad (indeed, if there is a good, clear, lucid answer explaining the idea it's often regarded as a good question)

Comment: @gview I really don't think the personal circumstances of the asker should be relevant. There are plenty of professional programmers and students who ask terrible questions, and it is not implausible that a non-programmer, with no interest in the relevant technologies other than for solving some immediate problem, might come here and succeed in formulating a good question.

Comment: If the primary purpose of the site is to create a repository of useful answers, it stands to reason that any focus towards programmers or any other particular class of person would be only because they are more likely to generate quality questions.  Consider that incidental.  It's not like anyone would see an answer to a question, use it to implement a solution, only to later exclaim 'Wait, a NON-PROGRAMMER asked that question?!' and immediately destroy their own work.

Comment: Fwiw, this question also does not necessarily do a good job of providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Although he does have a specific question in there, he's providing about 2 pages of code and also asking "why doesn't this thing work", whereas he should be asking something more like "based on my understanding variable X should have Y data in data but I get Q instead and I don't understand why".  Seems to me the question could be closed the way any other missing-MCVE question could, and it would also help guide the poster to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: I am a relatively new contributor to SO (and also answered the question) so this should be taken into account.
I agree that the original was very far from being a good question as per the guide but I think that the updated question is much better. I do think that there is definitely long-term benefit for future developers. I think that the updated question and revised answer could help someone else:I remember when I first started out this was a problem that I encountered and took a while to figure out. This is why I was happy to invest the time in answering. All this assumes it's no duplicate